# Pandas series: find the sum of values in a period of one month each time

Tags: python, pandas, series

Assume we have the series:

```
2015-12-19 00:00:00 0.02347
2015-12-19 01:00:00 0.02152
2015-12-19 02:00:00 0.02329
2015-12-19 03:00:00 0.02045
2015-12-19 04:00:00 0.01962
2015-12-19 05:00:00 0.01896
2015-12-19 06:00:00 0.02184
2015-12-19 07:00:00 0.0239
2015-12-19 08:00:00 0.02928
2015-12-19 09:00:00 0.03008
2015-12-19 10:00:00 0.03007
.
.
.
2016-08-18 23:00:00 0.02892
```

I want to find the sum of the values every month but not from the 1st of each month. I want to find for example the sum of values: 
from 19-12-2015 to 18-1-2016
from 19-1-2016 to 18-2-2016
etc.

Comment: Are you always going to start the 19th of each month? what about starting on 30th or 31st?

Comment: I think that the method below, proposed by @KarelZe solve this problem.

Comment: It depends on your expectation or definition of a month in terns of days. For instance,  if you are standing on Jan 31st, what would you like it to be the end date? Feb 28 or  March the 2nd?  If a couple of days more or less and dates overlapping is not a great deal, the below is a good approximation.

Comment: That's a problem, what about user gives only values up to 28 ?

Comment: I would first compute end of interval dates up to the last date in your data, then create a map column to each interval (bucket) and then groupby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
import pandas as pd
import io   

data = """2015-12-19 00:00:00;0.02347
2015-12-19 01:00:00; 0.02152
2015-12-19 02:00:00; 0.02329
2015-12-19 03:00:00; 0.02045
2015-12-19 04:00:00; 0.01962
2015-12-19 05:00:00; 0.01896
2015-12-19 06:00:00; 0.02184
2015-12-19 07:00:00; 0.0239
2015-12-19 08:00:00; 0.02928
2016-12-19 09:00:00; 0.03008
2016-12-20 10:00:00; 0.03007"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=";", header=None, index_col=0, parse_dates=True)

# subtract 19 days
df.index = df.index - pd.Timedelta(days=19)
# sum months
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).sum()
# apply offsets again
df.index = df.index + pd.Timedelta(days=19)
```

Comment: I think it's correct. Smart!

Comment: @tasos_koukos Glad to hear.